# Can't add PPA repo to Linux Mint 21.1

Tags: linux-mint, ppa

I'm Using Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon, I was going to edit and add a PPA with `pkexec mintsources` or **Software Source** a GUI Linux Mint app to add and edit PPAs and so my **Software Manager** and **Update Manager** isn't working. I can't open them at all. so I tried to add a PPA in the terminal then I noticed it's not working and this is the problem:

```
:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
LSB codename: 'jammy'.
Version of base-files: '12ubuntu4.2'.
Your LSB codename isn't a valid Linux Mint codename.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".
```

This repo belongs to this software
[GRASS GIS 8.2.1](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/linux/#GRASS-GIS-current) and its [repo](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable) for ubuntu. before I try to install GRASS GIS I did the same thing for [FreeCAD](https://wiki.freecad.org/Installing_on_Linux#Stable_PPA_version:%7E:text=the%20development%20branch.-,Stable%20PPA%20version,-Warning%3A%20The) and there was no problem.

Based on the information above For Linux Mint it shouldn't be like that! the results below are for an Ubuntu OS but I'm using Linux Mint not Ubuntu! so I run this command and I get this:

```
:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

This is wrong and I want to know how to change these from Ubuntu to Linux Mint. My problem is these settings instead of Ubuntu must be Linux Mint, Vera, 21.1 and so on.

After I ran this command `inxi -Fxxxxrz` to get all information about my OS, even here you can see it says `No active apt repos in:`

```
:~$ inxi -Fxxxxrz
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-60-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.7 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin vt: 7
    dm: GDM3 42.0, LightDM 1.30.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: X541UVK v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X541UVK v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: X541UVK.308 date: 01/30/2018
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 19.6 Wh (100.0%) condition: 19.6/34.6 Wh (56.6%)
    volts: 10.8 min: 10.8 model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery type: Li-ion serial: N/A
    status: Not charging cycles: 1902
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check rev: 9 cache: L1: 128 KiB
    L2: 512 KiB L3: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 800 min/max: 400/3500 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800
    4: 800 bogomips: 23199
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel
    ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1,HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:5916 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 920MX] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia
    v: 525.78.01 pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 4 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:134f class-ID: 0302
  Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-6:3 chip-ID: 13d3:5a01 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 102 s-size: 480x270mm (18.9x10.6")
    s-diag: 551mm (21.7")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1-1 mapped: eDP-1 model: BOE Display res: 1920x1080 hz: 60
    dpi: 142 size: 344x193mm (13.5x7.6") diag: 394mm (15.5") modes: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce 920MX/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.78.01 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
    class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-60-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.64 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: d000
    bus-ID: 02:00.2 chip-ID: 10ec:8136 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp2s0f2 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lite-On
    driver: rtl8723be v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: c000
    bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:b723 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-f0e6bdaf9d81 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: kvnet state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-8:4 chip-ID: 0bda:b721 class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.13 TiB used: 1.06 TiB (94.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WDS240G2G0A-00JH30
    size: 223.58 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 0000
    scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM035-1RK172 size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 5400 serial: <filter> rev: SDM1 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 218.52 GiB used: 187.83 GiB (86.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 8 GiB used: 298.5 MiB (3.6%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C pch: 41.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia
    temp: 46 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 2400
Repos:
  Packages: 5322 apt: 5301 snap: 21
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cappelikan-ppa-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/connectify.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eivnaes-network-manager-sstp-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/element-io.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freecad-maintainers-freecad-stable-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphic-drivers-ppa.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/inkscape_dev-stable-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kdenlive-kdenlive-stable-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kicad-kicad-6_0-releases-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-beta.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nm-l2tp-network-manager-l2tp-jammy.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-obs-studio-jammy.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/obsproject-obs-studio-jammy.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb http://mirror.rasanegar.com/linuxmint/packages vera main upstream import backport
    2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.asiatech.ir jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.asiatech.ir jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.asiatech.ir jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/remmina-ppa-team-remmina-next-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-digikam-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
    2: deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/uget-team-ppa-jammy.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zulu-openjdk.list
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zulu.list
Info:
  Processes: 315 Uptime: 4h 25m wakeups: 2 Memory: 7.65 GiB
  used: 3.16 GiB (41.4%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11/12 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16 running-in: gnome-terminal
  inxi: 3.3.13
```

Why are they pointing to Ubuntu? It's like I installed the last version of Ubuntu. Does adding an Ubuntu PPA to Linux Mint change Linux Mint from Mint to Ubuntu?

Just to clarify that I'm Using Linux Mint Not Ubuntu:

[image: Just to clarify that I'm Using Linux Mint Not Ubuntu]

edit:

```
:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
deb http://mirror.rasanegar.com/linuxmint/packages vera main upstream import backport 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.asiatech.ir jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.asiatech.ir jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.asiatech.ir jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu PPAs should be fine, as long as the Ubuntu base matches the version used by Mint; in this case, yours is correct. On that note, I've never experienced a release change like that trying to add a PPA. Please add the results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Nashenas, it is much clearer now!